# Differentiable sequence of functions does not converge

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

> If {${f_n}$} (defined on $R$) is differentiable for all $n$ and {${f'_n}$} converges uniformly is it possible for {${f_n}$} to not converge for any $x$ in $R$.

Can you show your efforts in here?

Edit: Thanks I now see it is obvious, will start by plugging in things like x + n in future.

Comment: Define $f_n=r_n,$ where $r_1,r_2,\dots $ is an enumeration of the rationals.

Comment: This is a variant of my 2nd example :)

Comment: First you should show some efforts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f_n(x)=x+n$. What about such sequence?

Comment: And $f_n(x)=x+\sin(n)$ for a "bounded" example.

Comment: Another one $f_n(x)=a_nx+b_n$, where $(a_n)$ converges while $(b_n)$ diverges.